# Querying record existence using placeholders in the WHERE clause

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing a Login python script that validates if the user account is present in the SQLite database. How do I insert placeholders in my sql statement in order to verify user input against records present in the database table? or what other alternative can I apply without using the for loop which could be slow if the database is huge?

Using python3 as my base code and integrating Sqlite for the database, I've tried using the EXISTS clause after user input by including placeholders for the values that represent user input. The Exists clause usually returns 1(True) or 0(False) which I have assigned to a variable so that if checked against 'IF selector' should verify whether account record exists in the 'Log' table or not.

```
            print('Logging into an existing account...')
            try:
                self.user = input('Enter user name: ')
                self.pas = input('Enter password: ')
                self.log = (self.user,self.pas)
                self.sql = '''SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Log WHERE 
                Name=? AND Password=?);'''
                self.cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Log;')             
                self.val = self.cur.execute(self.sql,self.log)
                if self.val == 1:
                    print(f'\nLogged in as {self.user}')
                    time.sleep(2)
                else:
                    print('\nAccount is non-existent!')
                    time.sleep(2)
```

Expected result: Presence of user record in accordance to the EXISTS clause should always return 1, which if validated by the 'IF selector' should be 'True' thus output "Logged in as (user)".

Actual result: The output is "Account is non-existent" despite presence of user record in the database table with no errors.

Comment: Are you sure `execute()` returns an integer?

Comment: No, execute parses the SQL statements and a tuple. To obtain values of the execute() function, I must fetch them from the database using fetchone() or fetchall().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute() parses the SQL statements and a tuple.In my case the tuple contained my variables. I therefore just had to fetch the value returned by execute() function using fetchone(). Presuming the returned value must be a row containing an integer by inference, I assigned it to variable and applied indexing to determine the actual value.On testing using IF I got the expected result!

```
                self.sql = '''SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Log WHERE Name=? AND 
                Password=?);'''
                self.cur.execute(self.sql,self.log)
                self.val = self.cur.fetchone()
                if self.val[0]==1:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print(f'\nLogged in as {self.user}\n')
```